# Encrypt Oracle Database Passwords using Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, encryption, cryptography, cx-oracle

So what we've got is some processes that log into databases and we need to have the credentials for that encrypted (at least the password). What we're looking for is the ability to call something that will encrypt and decrypt the password when called so we can use that for the credentials.  Something like the below:

Start program

call external decryption program to get credentials

connect to database

do stuff

disconnect

end program

So basically I would like to encrypt the password so that it's not sitting stored as plain text. I have seen a variety of solutions using Wallet's and Python Cyrptography library. Where I am stuck is how to deploy my solution so that only the correct oracle user with permissions is able to decrypt the password file. Is there a way to validate the Oracle user using CX_Oracle?

Below find my current .py file with my connection to CX_Oracle:

```
import cx_Oracle


def get_ldif_string(row, isFirst):
  ldif = ""

if isFirst == False:
    ldif += "\r\n"

ldif += "dn: sk-ban=" + \
    row[0] + ",ou=XXXXXXXX,ou=XXXXXXXXX,ou=XXXXXX,dc=XXXXXXXXX,dc=com" + "\r\n"

ldif += "objectClass: sk-account\r\n"
ldif += "objectClass: top\r\n"

ldif += "sk-ban: " + row[0] + "\r\n"

if row[1].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingFullName: " + row[1] + "\r\n"

if row[3].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingAddress: " + row[3] + "\r\n"

if row[4].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingCity: " + row[4] + "\r\n"

if row[5].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingProvince: " + row[5] + "\r\n"

if row[6].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingPostalCode: " + row[6] + "\r\n"

if row[7].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingAccountType: " + row[7] + "\r\n"

if row[8].strip():
    ldif += "sk-billingServiceNumber: " + row[8] + "\r\n"

if row[9].strip():
    ldif += "sk-active: " + row[9] + "\r\n"

if row[10].strip():
    ldif += "sk-inactive: " + row[10] + "\r\n"

#print (ldif)
return ldif


def writeToFile(textToWrite, file):
  file.write(textToWrite)


dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(
  'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXX', service_name='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(
user=r'XXXXXXX', password=r'XXXXXXX', dsn=dsn_tns)


query = """Select * FROM (
select 
COALESCE(ACCT_NO, ' ') as ACCT_NO
, COALESCE(BILLING_FIRST_NAME, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(BRM_LAST_NAME, '')
, COALESCE(BRM_LAST_NAME, ' ')
, COALESCE(BRM_ADDRESS, ' ')
, COALESCE(BRM_CITY, ' ')
, COALESCE(BRM_PROVINCE, ' ') 
, COALESCE(BRM_POSTAL_CODE, ' ')
, COALESCE(BRM_ACCOUNT_TYPE, ' ')
, COALESCE(CRB_TN_SN, ' ')
, CASE WHEN BRM_DEAL_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN COALESCE(BRM_DEAL_NAME, ' ') ELSE ' ' END as BRM_ACTIVE
, CASE WHEN BRM_DEAL_STATUS <> 'ACTIVE' THEN COALESCE(BRM_DEAL_NAME, ' ') ELSE ' ' END as 
BRM_INACTIVE
from PIN.V_SK_IDM_DATA
ORDER BY ACCT_NO
)
--where ACCT_NO in ('7135942-00002', '7133100', '7206065-00011', '0042006-00003', '0044070-00001')
"""

fileName = "load/loadLDIF.ldif"
open(fileName, 'w').close()
file = open(fileName, "a+")

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(query)

ban = ""
ldif = ""
isFirst = True

for row in c:

newBan = row[0]
if newBan != ban:
    writeToFile(ldif, file)
    ldif = get_ldif_string(row, isFirst)
    isFirst = False
    ban = newBan
else:
    if row[9].strip():
        ldif += "sk-active: " + row[9] + "\r\n"
    else:
        ldif += "sk-inactive: " + row[10] + "\r\n"


writeToFile(ldif, file)
conn.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: Have you considered using an Oracle wallet? In that setup you would leave the username/password empty in your file and let the Oracle Client fill it in automatically. You can set it up so that each OS user has their own wallet and they can't be exported from the system they are created on.

Comment: I will give Oracle Wallet a look thank you!